# Using template driven form with dynamic input list (ngFor)

Tags: angular, angular2-forms, ngfor

I am new to web development and is working on a MEAN stack project using angular2. 
I am trying to add template-driven form with dynamic list of input using ngFor - however I did observe an abnormal behavior with the way I implement it. I am wondering if I am doing it the right way...

Abnormal behavior: If I were to add 2 or more input field and remove the non-last-entries input, the next time i add the new entries, it resets all the entries below the one I just deleted. In addition, somehow the new entries are binding with the entries above?

[demo of the issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F8xUm.gif)

Here is my plunker:
http://plnkr.co/edit/FjLg8VDDo3E6fHVgS8ah?p=preview

Here is the way that I implement template driven form with dynamic input using ngFor. I was referring to another stackoverflow post:angular-2-template-driven-form-with-ngfor-inputs

```
<div *ngFor="let hero of heroArray; let i = index">

             <div class="form-group">
            <label for="name">Name</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="name"
                   required
                   [(ngModel)]="hero.name" name="name-{{i}}"
                   #name="ngModel" >
            <div [hidden]="name.valid || name.pristine"
                 class="alert alert-danger">
              Name is required
            </div>
          </div>
      </div>
```

Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I like questions with the demonstration on the Plunkr:)

I suppose that the problem is related with your `name` property. It should be unique name. Using index as unique value is wrong. It will be mixed after changing your array.

So i offer you to use `id` as unique name:

```
let uniqueId = 1;
...
addNewHero(){
  var hero: Hero  = new Hero(uniqueId++,'','');
  this.heroArray.push(hero);
}
```

and in html:

```
<input type="text" ... name="name-{{hero.id}}">
```

Here is the **[Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/NUvQnoDqshTn4GASkyTo?p=preview)**