# Validate input inside a ngFor using template driven forms

Tags: angular, validation

In our Angular form (we are using [template driven forms](https://angular.io/guide/forms#template-driven-forms)) we have a list of input fields which are rendered dynamically, as so, we need to validate then. Following this: [Using template driven form with dynamic input list (ngFor)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39672719/using-template-driven-form-with-dynamic-input-list-ngfor) I didn't come any further as it seems to be outdated, as the plunkr sample is not working.

that is our **tbody** which renders our list:

```
  <tbody>
    <tr *ngFor="let item of items; let i=index">
      <td><span>{{ item.categoryName }}</span></td>
      <td class="text-right">
        <input *ngIf="editMode" 
          type="number" 
          tabindex="1" 
          autocomplete="off" 
          [(ngModel)]="item.value" name="value-{{item.categoryId}}" #value="ngModel"
          required 
        />
        {{value.valid}} <!--As I'm using ngForm I was expecting to receive false or true here-->
        <span *ngIf="!editMode">{{ item.value }}</span>
      </td>
      <td>
        <app-status [status]="item.status"></app-status>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
```

This works fine, the list  can be seen, but the validation does not work.

if I try: `{{value.valid}}` I get the following error:

> ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'valid' of undefined

Means, my instance of ngModel did't work.

What am I missing?

Comment: The problem here may be the template reference variable. You have the *same* template reference variable on each input box. According to the documentation: `The scope of a reference variable is the entire template. Do not define the same variable name more than once in the same template. The runtime value will be unpredictable.` from: https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax#template-reference-variables--var-

Comment: I didn't get your point

Comment: for each input box, you are defining a `value` variable, but the scope of that variable is not isolated to the input box, it's able to be referenced by the whole scope of the template. So especially where you're looping through and creating these separately in your template, it's possible that something gets messed up along the way, hence the warning:

Comment: #value is a template reference variable. You are adding a template reference variable with this *same* name to *every* input box. According to the documentation, you should not use the same template reference variable more than once in a template.

Comment: what is the solution if I have an iteration? create a scoped function that validates my vaule for me? then there is no need of the `required` attribute?

Answer (score 0):

Where are you trying to do `{{value.valid}}`? I don't see that here so I don't know what would be causing a null definition of value.

Rather than using an attribute of `value`, you could have a function in your component that does the validation check for you.

```
<tr *ngFor="let item of items; let i = index">
  <!-- somewhere in your code -->
  <div *ngIf="myValidationFunction(value)">
    <!-- stuff -->
  </div>
```

Then in your ts file, you could have something that does a check on it. If it is always required, it's pretty simple to do.

```
myValidationFunction(value) {
    if (value) {
        // results to 'true' if value isn't null
        return value.valid; // where valid is some field in value
    }
    else { // if value is null, you can say that it is wrong
        return false; // this means that it will not be valid until it's defined
    }
```

Comment: This is a good solution, so what is the point of using ngForm at all? I've been trying to implement a complex form with angular for hours and I don't get the point why this is so difficult. According to your snippet I would not rely on ngForm and I would have my own validation function. I will update my code so you can see where is the {{value.valid}}

Comment: Template driven forms provide a simple and straightforward solution for simple and straightforward forms. For more complete forms such as your example, try using Reactive Forms instead. They are set up to easily add any number of controls or groups of controls to your form.

Comment: I feel that using a form produces cleaner and more maintainable code, especially if you're using their [built in](https://angular.io/guide/form-validation#reactive-forms-with-validation-in-code) form stuff. There's a lot of functionality you get right out of the box, like a min/max length of input, a required field, etc. I just looked it up, and it seems that you can define your own validation functions of type `ValidatorFn`, whatever that means. I haven't looked into it at all, just something I stumbled upon.

Comment: Just to be clear ... Reactive Forms also uses a form and makes use of all of the built-in validation such as min/max length, required, etc. And yes, you can build your own validators for template-driven or reactive forms.

Comment: I tried Reactive Forms as well and it's also not easy once you have lists and children forms. My problem with Reactive Forms was that I have two instances of a grid on the same page which share the same `formArrayName` and to solve that I had to pass `formArrayName` as `@Input` from the children to the parent, horrible!

Comment: When all else fails, you hack it out with pure javascript and html, because that always seems to work... I'm not a frontend developer and I would never claim to be one.